# How do I render a form?

Tags: forms, 8

What is the alternative to `drupal_get_form('user_login')`. in Drupal 8?

I am using the following code in theme_name.theme, but it doesn't work.

```
// Include namespace for userLoginForm.
use \Drupal\Core\core\modules\user\src\Form;

function MYTHEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $form = UserLoginForm::create();
}
```

Answer (score 36):

`drupal_get_form()` has been replaced by the form builder service, e.g.:

```
$form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm(\Drupal\user\Form\UserLoginForm::class);
```

See the [Change Record](https://www.drupal.org/node/2121003) for more details.

Actually, don't - that change record is incorrect. It'll tell you to pass the form ID, when in fact you need to pass the class string.

Answer (score 15):

You can create a form under form folder . And then you can call your form anywhere and pass the paramater as shown.

**Drupal 7** : `$form = drupal_get_form('form_id',$parameter);`

**Drupal 8** : `$form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\custom_module\Form\CustomModuleForm',$parameter);`

Comment: How to get a node add form, for eg: add article form (/node/add/article) ?

Comment: +1, you can pass it without $parameter in controller as well.

Answer (score 8):

There are two options to return(D8) or render(D7) a form. These are `\Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm` and `Drupal::formBuilder()->buildForm`. I use **`\Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm`** as below.

Use this if **you are not passing** a parameter:

```
$form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('\Drupal\example\Form\ExampleForm');
return $form;
```

Use this if **you are passing** a parameter:

```
$parameter = "your_parameter";
$form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('\Drupal\example\Form\ExampleForm', $parameter);
return $form;
//pass to formbuild function
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $parameter = NULL){//form code}
```

---

Drupal 7 Equivalent of the above:

```
$parameter = 'your_parameter';
$form = drupal_get_form('form_id', $parameter);
print drupal_render($form);
//pass to form function
function form_id ($form, &$form_state, $parameter){//form code}
```

Cheers. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Gosh, it took me ages again, although you even cover this in your answer, that the additional parameter passed to `buildForm` must always be initiated with `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation does allow an instance of the class as well. So

```
$formObj = new \Drupal\demo\Form\MyForm();
$form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($formObj);
```

is also correct.

Comment: Probably don't do this. In case the form class uses dependency injection, you've circumvented it here. Better off to let the form builder instantiate the class unless you have a good reason to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Ok if all else fails here is a sneaky trick by setting a new form state object.

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormState;
...

$form_state = new FormState();
$form_state->set('name', $name);
$form_state->set('user', $user);
$render_array = \Drupal::formBuilder()->buildForm('\Drupal\mod\Form\MyForm', $form_state);
...
// Example render.
$response = new AjaxResponse();
// Show a dialog box.
$dialogText['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';
$response->addCommand(new OpenModalDialogCommand("Dialog Title", $render_array, ['width' => '300']));
return $response;
```

... then in your form method buildForm  you can then...

```
 // Get form state.
 $name = $form_state->get('name');
 if (!empty($name)) {
    $form['name'] = [
      '#type' => 'item',
      '#markup' => $name,
    ];
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the below is your form class

```
namespace Drupal\demo\Form;
use \Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
class MyForm extends FormBase {
}
```

You have to create a new instance from your form class first, and pass it to formBuilder's getForm.

```
$form_obj = new \Drupal\demo\Form\MyForm();
$form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($form_obj);
```

Comment: You don't "have to create a new instance" - this is wrong. You should be passing the class string.