# Why doesn't loading a form in the view header work?

Tags: forms, 8

I've been checking for the past 2 days on how to do a drupal_get_form() for Drupal 8 and everyone seems to give me the following answers which don't seem to work. Let's just say I want to take the following **Basic Page** creation form and embed it into a Views header:

[image]

The ID of the form is: **node-page-form** or **node_page_form** if we were using drupal_get_form() from Drupal 7. But this time its the following:

**$form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm(Drupal\user\Form\NodePageForm::class);**

**I'm assuming "NodePageForm" is the parameter I'm suppose to use. If not how can one find this out from viewing the source of that page?**

I then put the following PHP code in the Views header of my page like this:

[image]

I click save and update... my header is blank. What did I do wrong?

I'm trying to be as descriptive as I can explaining this problem. End result I just want to be able to take **ANY** form from any D8 page and be able to render it anywhere that takes PHP. That's my end goal. So no 3rd party modules as a solution.

Comment: Should not the PHP code exclude the `<?php ?>` tag?

Comment: I started writing an answer to this but it's getting out of hand, there's quite a bit of info to get across. Here's the first bit at least, hope it helps clear that part up: http://pastebin.com/hu2SrZiX

Comment: The first part of the second part included this:  _there isn't a way to identify the class that implements a form from its markup alone; you need to dig into the code._ I'm pretty sure that holds true

Comment: So for Drupal 8 every time I see a form I'd like to render somewhere else I would need to do a grep in the codebase to find that form then look for the form_id? What would I need to grep for if thats the case?

Comment: @LittleCoding I did that if you looked at my code above. It doesn't work. I don't understand why its so difficult. All I want to do is find a form somewhere on the site and output it elsewhere in a PHP enabled text field. That is all. Apparently its more difficult that just D7's drupal_get_form() function method.

Comment: That's what I've been trying to explain (maybe not very well), it's not that simple any more. You can't look at the markup for the form and know what to grep for, definitely not for entity forms. But that's because those are built up with the `EntityFormBuilder` service, and an instance of an entity which you set up manually. See [this](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21tests%21Drupal%21Tests%21Core%21Entity%21EntityFormBuilderTest.php/class/EntityFormBuilderTest/8.2.x) for an example. I'm not being obtuse; the simple, catch-all, generic solution you want doesn't exist as far as I know

Comment: Ok so let me get this straight. Just looking at **ANY** form on Drupal 8 and wanting to render it else where by trying to find a **form_id** of some sort isn't going to work anymore. So can we safely say in order for us as a dev to find these forms to render elsewhere we'd have to at least know  which module to look in. Say in my case its has to do with rendering the node creation form. So I goto the **node module** folder and grep for **EntityFormBuilder** and find the class name? And I'm assuming if there are multiple class names, we'd have to trial and error it. Is that correct?

Comment: Many times I have to render forms from other parts of the site and it would be great if we can document a STEP by STEP tutorial for others to follow when needing this setup something like this. In D7 it was just finding the form_id which was simple enough and just doing a drupal_get_form(). It's okay if its more steps in D8, but we should at least figure out a **universal** step by step guide on rendering forms from other parts of the site.

Comment: I'll give it one more go, I'm running out of different ways to say it: **there isn't a universal, step by step guide**. Different forms come from different parts of the system, and so require different knowledge to locate. You don't have to agree that it's a good thing, you dont have t like it, but you can't keep on ignoring what I've said to you in three or four different ways now. What you want doesn't exist, please accept it and move on!

Answer (score 3):

sEntity forms should be built using the [entity.form_builder](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.services.yml/service/entity.form_builder/8.2.x) service. You'll need an entity to work with, for a node your code might change to something like this:

```
$node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('node')
  ->create(['type' => 'page']);

$form = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($node);

print \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($form);
```

As noted in the comments, this won't actually work in the context you're using it, regardless of how you render the form. The views_php area handler renders the output of the custom PHP using `#markup`, which will strip out the `<input>` and other form tags. You'll need a custom or contributed module, or to alter the views_php module directly, to make this work.

Here's a simple area handler that adds support for common form tags:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\foo\Plugin\views\area;

use Drupal\Component\Utility\Xss;
use Drupal\views_php\Plugin\views\area\ViewsPhp;

/**
 * Views area PHP text handler with support for common form tags.
 *
 * @ingroup views_area_handlers
 *
 * @ViewsArea("foo")
 */
class ViewsPhpForm extends ViewsPhp {

  public function render($empty = FALSE) {
    if (!$empty || !empty($this->options['empty'])) {
      $content = $this->renderViewsPhp($this->options['content']);
      $form_tags = ['form', 'input', 'select', 'fieldset', 'option', 'button', 'textarea', 'optgroup'];
      $allowed_tags = array_merge(Xss::getAdminTagList(), $form_tags);

      return [
        '#type' => 'inline_template',
        '#template' => Xss::filter($content, $allowed_tags),
      ];
    }

    return [];
  }

}
```

This code should be in `src/Plugin/views/area/ViewsPhpForm.php` and will need updating for the name of your module.

You'll also need to make views aware of it with a hook either in your .module file, or foo.views.inc:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data().
 */
function foo_views_data() {
  $data['views']['php_with_form'] = [
    'title' => t('PHP with form'),
    'help' => t('Use PHP code with support for form tags.'),
    'area' => [
      'id' => 'foo',
    ],
  ];

  return $data;
}
```

After a cache rebuild you'll be able to add a new area handler, *PHP with form*, and your form should be rendered.

Comment: I tested your answer, but didn't work properly, this is what I got https://drt5a.ply.st/test

Comment: Works well for me @NoSssweat: http://imgur.com/SM8uKIq, how are you rendering it?

Comment: like OPer wants it, at the header of a View Page.

Comment: The fact that the button text is "asdf" makes me think you have something altering that form...

Comment: I just gave anonymous all permissions, see https://drt5a.ply.st/test again, and edit view if you like.

Comment: But the submit button for a node form isn't "sadf"...so you have some code altering that form somehow, which might be causing the problem?

Comment: asdf is the title of a random node I created (comes from field title of the view). https://drt5a.ply.st/admin/structure/views/view/test/edit/page_1?destination=test

Comment: Oh wait, you're probably right, the global text header may be run through a filter, removing the `<input>` tags. Not sure if Views has an option to disable that filtering

Comment: it might be because views doesn't know which content type form to load, Article? Basic Page? how would **Views Page** know? I gonna try with block.

Comment: It works it out from the entity, it's been set up with `->create(['type' => 'page'])`, that could just as easily by `->create(['type' => 'article'])`, and so on. I tested this by returning it from a controller (don't like turning on the PHP filter on principal!), where it works fine. But it makes sense that Views might push the output of the global header through a filter format. In fact that might be where this could be attacked, but it might mean making the default format more permissive. Not sure

Comment: It worked fine for me placing the code on a regular block. Looks like you're right, there is some sort of views filtering going on. I guess the OPer will have to use a regular block and place it before his view. **PS:** I also condone using/enableing PHP Filter on anything.

Comment: Turns out it's the views_php module itself that's responsible, not Views @NoSssweat, I added a bit to the answer

Comment: Thanks Clive. I can confirm the first block of code does indeed work when I copy and paste it to my custom module code. It does indeed render the node creation form, but I still have a question after that: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/210496/what-are-the-variables-does-one-search-for-when-trying-to-render-a-custom-form-o

Answer (score 1):

See [How to render form in drupal 8](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/182406/61278). Also has a link to the Change Record over on Drupal.org

Comment: Thats not the point. All I'm looking for is what is the exact code you need to just output / print a form that resides somewhere else on the site. Thats it. I've already checked that link. It doesnt work.

Comment: Then how about go at this from the opposite direction. Try `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter` to render your view as part of the form.