# What are the variables does one search for when trying to render a custom form?

Tags: forms, 8

In Drupal 8, the following code renders the node creation form (node/add/page) when integrating it into a custom module:

```
$node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('node')
  ->create(['type' => 'page']);

$form = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($node);

print \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($form);
```

We know the module in question is the Node module, which generates the content type page. What should I do to render the user creation form (/admin/people/create)?

I can easily change the code to the following, and replace `'node'` with `'user'` and `'page'` with `'user`'.

```
  ->getStorage('user')
  ->create(['type' => 'user']);
```

This would now render the user creation form. For me to come to the conclusion that it would render the user form was only a guess and apparently it works. But this problem solving approach will not work if I wanted to render some other form that might not be so obvious.

What does one have to grep for in the code base or other investigative work to come to the conclusion of the following 2 lines in the above code?

Comment: I stand by my [previous comment](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/208743/why-doesnt-loading-a-form-in-the-view-header-work#comment254934_208743), it applies directly to this question too. By the time you know what to grep for, you'll already have more than enough context to tell you what class defines the form, making the grep redundant

Comment: Ok, taking your stance of **by the time you know what to grep for, you'll already have more than enough context**... Then before you even grep it, you still have to compile all the hints from something. That something is the thing I want to know. Even if it requires 20 other steps before it to conclude on what to grep for. Reason why is being able to debug a form, you'd first have to know where it came from. How does a developer know where it came from? Does one use devel? Or does one just look for something in the html source? I'm trying to take a step by step approach to understanding this.

Comment: I've already answered thst exact question from you 3 or more times now. Not doing it again, sorry, I don't have another way to phrase it :)

Comment: :( I just don't agree that there is absolutely no way for someone coming to D8 to not be able to debug a form by saying there are **absolutely** no universal steps into debugging this. It could even be as simple as grep for the label of the input box. That could be one universal method. No worries Clive!!! I'll figure it out.... but your hints have given me a lead at least. I just want to understand this system better before pushing it to clients. Thanks for everything thus far.

Comment: Happy to help - and also more than happy to be proven wrong by someone!

Comment: In OOP, reading document of interface is very important for understanding how further you work with them. If you know Java and other OOP, you will understand that. It is the reason why many Java programmers cannot work without a IDE....

Comment: My main workspace is Vim and bash commands (I do alot of grepping) and my workflow is usually I find something I want to change, I'd inspect element it, find some hints to grep for. Then start grepping everywhere until I narrow it down to the source file that might be in question. Then do some output debug test to make sure I'm in the right place and then work from there on modifications. But your saying D8's OOP setup I wouldn't be able to do this?

Comment: At the risk of being bashed (no pun intended)  by devs older than myself - unless you're a ninja with it, or have the natural lean towards becoming one, vim is rarely the tool to use any more. Our brains work much better with graphical UIs. Generally speaking, of course, thst won't apply to everyone, and it's just my experience and the devs I've known over the last 15 years. But using a graphical IDE like PHPStorm makes debugging and following the code trail 1000% easier. You should try it for a bit, at least so you can see the difference

Comment: The way you usually work, as you've outlined, is basically dependant on one thing: being able to reverse engineer the source of markup from the markup itself. _That's_ the difference here. You can still use grep to find things, assuming you actually know what to search for. That info isn't in the HTML any more, so you need somewhere else t get thst info from. And the only places are 1. Someone telling you, or 2. Looking at the code. Option 2 also requires some working knowledge of Drupal's architecture

Answer (score 1):

To answer your explicit question (and to reiterate what Clive said), there's no one thing that you could grep to conclude the arguments to change for the [`getStorage()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!EntityManager.php/function/EntityManager%3A%3AgetStorage/8.2.x) & [`create()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityStorageInterface.php/function/EntityStorageInterface%3A%3Acreate/8.2.x) methods.

The above solution assumes:

1. You're looking for an entity form.
2. You're aware that [`EntityFormBuilderInterface::getForm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityFormBuilderInterface.php/function/EntityFormBuilderInterface%3A%3AgetForm/8.2.x) needs an entity object.
3. You can build an entity object with [`Drupal::entityTypeManager()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityTypeManager/8.2.x).

It's a specific solution to building *entity forms*. If you're looking for a method to find any *arbitrary constructed form*, this solution isn't going to help here.

The most generic thing one could search for to find such a form (an invoke it for rendering), is probably a label that is unique to the custom form, but it really depends on how the form is constructed (e.g. [`EntityFormBuilderInterface::getForm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityFormBuilderInterface.php/function/EntityFormBuilderInterface%3A%3AgetForm/8.2.x), [`FormBuilderInterface::getForm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormBuilderInterface.php/function/FormBuilderInterface%3A%3AgetForm/8.2.x), or some arbitrary form array builder function).

If you're familiar with the pattern of construction, there might be some specific terms to search for (e.g. searching for classes implementing [`FormBuilderInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormBuilderInterface.php/interface/FormBuilderInterface/8.2.x) or [`EntityFormBuilderInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityFormBuilderInterface.php/interface/EntityFormBuilderInterface/8.2.x)), but there's not going to be one search pattern that works for all forms.