# Display the node edit form on a node view page

Tags: nodes, 8

Can we show the node edit form in a custom block and show that on a node view page?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! The question is too broad for us.  If you are asking about code to write, you should show what code you wrote so far; if you are asking about modules, requests for modules are off-topic for us.

Comment: I think this newly created module https://www.drupal.org/project/same_page_preview might be what you were looking for. Adding as a comment since the question got closed back then.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Form Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/formblock) module and place the block above your view block. Some details about it (from its project page):

> Enables the presentation of user registration, site wide contact, or node creation forms in blocks.

OR go with Clive's answer to this Q: [Why doesn't loading a form in the view header work?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/208743/why-doesnt-loading-a-form-in-the-view-header-work) and load the form in your View's header.

Comment: On each node/{nid} there will be a edit link on the right top. Clicking on the  link will open a popup having node edit settings  including menu settings, url path etc, where user can update the node data.

Comment: Give this a try [Creating modal windows (pop-ups) in Drupal 8: full tutorial](http://internetdevels.com/blog/creating-popups-in-Drupal-8)

Comment: 1) Need to embed node/{nid}/edit form in a custom block and it will place on its node/{nid} page.

Comment: Please check my minor edit. If the quote is not appropriate, feel free to adapt, or even rollback if you don't like it. IMO it reduces the risk of your answer being considered as "link only". OK?