# How do I programmatically generate an entity form?

Tags: forms, 8

I need to programmatically generate the entity form for my custom entity - basically get the same output that happens when you call

```
\Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('form namespace')
```

When I try to do that with my entity form **I get the error**:

```
Call to a member function getEntityTypeId() on null in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityForm->getBaseFormId() (line 77 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityForm.php).
```

Really stumped on how to proceed.

---

Here's an obfuscated version of code I'm using

Entity Definition:

```
/**
 * Defines the My Entity entity.
 *
 * @ingroup my_module
 *
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "my_entity",
 *   label = @Translation("My Entity"),
 *   handlers = {
 *     "view_builder" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder",
 *     "list_builder" = "Drupal\my_module\MyEntityListBuilder",
 *     "views_data" = "Drupal\my_module\Entity\MyEntityViewsData",
 *     "translation" = "Drupal\my_module\MyEntityTranslationHandler",
 *
 *     "form" = {
 *       "default" = "Drupal\my_module\Form\MyEntityForm",
 *       "add" = "Drupal\my_module\Form\MyEntityForm",
 *       "edit" = "Drupal\my_module\Form\MyEntityForm",
 *       "delete" = "Drupal\my_module\Form\MyEntityDeleteForm",
 *     },
 *     "access" = "Drupal\my_module\MyEntityAccessControlHandler",
 *     "route_provider" = {
 *       "html" = "Drupal\my_module\MyEntityHtmlRouteProvider",
 *     },
 *   },
 *   base_table = "my_entity",
 *   data_table = "my_entity_field_data",
 *   translatable = TRUE,
 *   admin_permission = "administer as my_entity entities",
 *   entity_keys = {
 *     "id" = "id",
 *     "label" = "name",
 *     "uuid" = "uuid",
 *     "uid" = "user_id",
 *     "langcode" = "langcode",
 *     "status" = "status",
 *   },
 *   links = {
 *     "canonical" = "/admin/structure/my_entity/{my_entity}",
 *     "add-form" = "/admin/structure/my_entity/add",
 *     "edit-form" = "/admin/structure/my_entity/{my_entity}/edit",
 *     "delete-form" = "/admin/structure/my_entity/{my_entity}/delete",
 *     "collection" = "/admin/structure/my_entity",
 *   },
 *   field_ui_base_route = "my_entity.settings",
 *   constraints = {
 *     "CustomContraint" = {}
 *   }
 * )
 */
class MyEntity extends ContentEntityBase implements MyEntityInterface {
```

Form namespace

```
namespace Drupal\my_module\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityForm;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Form controller for My Entity edit forms.
 *
 * @ingroup my_module
 */
class MyEntityForm extends ContentEntityForm {
```

---

Okay, so this is what I've found so far. User **oknate**'s answer partially works; I also had to add a dummy function to my container form class to get around a callback error, which looked like this:

```
 public function processForm($element, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form)
  {
    return $element;
  }
```

This is probably not the right way to do this, but it does result in a form object that will render in another form.

Comment: According to the docs the argument must either be the form ID or the class implementing the form. That form must implement FormInterface. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!FormBuilder.php/function/FormBuilder%3A%3AgetForm/8.2.x

Comment: Ex. \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm(Drupal\mymodule\Form\FormName)

Comment: See: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/182405/how-to-render-form-in-drupal-8

Comment: Yes, like I said I tried that.

Comment: My form does extend from the ContentEntityForm class, which implements the ContentEntityFormInterface, which extends the EntityFormInterface, which extends the BaseFromInterface, which extends the FormInterface, like you said.

Comment: Can you post the actual code then that you are using?

Comment: this is for register form in block in this
[link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/244651/19943)

Comment: this is for register form in block
[link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/244651/19943)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the entity form builder service.  I was able to load the user form this way (with $entity being the current user):

```
$entity = User::load($uid);
$user_form = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($entity, 'default');
```

If you want to get the user register form (which is basically an entity form without a saved entity), you can just use the create method on your entity class before passing it to the form:

```
$entity = User::create();
$user_form = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($entity, 'default');
```

Comment: Okay, this answer has gotten me the closest. When I try doing it, the page loads, but all that shows up is a warning that the form class I'm trying to inject the entity form into doesn't have a 'processForm' method.

Comment: The 'processForm' function seems to live in the \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityForm class.

Comment: Since the function just returns one of the arguments it receives ($element), I created a dummy version of that function in my container form class. After doing that, the entity form DOES render. I don't know what the consequences of bypassing that call are though.

Comment: @oknate, Thanks for your code, it works perfect, But, I want to attach #after_build method for ajax operations. The #after_build method is not firing/calling, Have you come across with this situation? or anyone has a solution to attach #after_build method

Comment: If you are using a build array to hold the form and you are using a template that renders the form properly, then it should work fine.  If you are having trouble with ajax not loading, you may be pre-rendering the form and then it's getting cached in the template, where it didn't properly signal to add the javascript on subsequent page loads.

Comment: Js is working, But hook_form_alter is not affecting, Suppose, I have added a callback function on #after_build ( _custom_after_build_method) , this method is not triggering after ajax call, Ajax call is working. but functionality which is specified in _custom_after_build_method is not affecting., 
$user_form = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($entity, 'default');
is rendering a plan form befor hook_form_alter, Now question is How to applay form_alter changes to Renderd form output?

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/238712/rendering-a-form-using-drupalserviceentity-form-builder-getformentity

Please check this question, I have explained my problem

Comment: What if you don't have a uid and just want to load the registration form?

Comment: Then use User:create() instead of User::load().  I have updated the answer with an example.

Comment: For the user registration example you might also want to use the 'register' form rather than the 'default' form, so the example becomes:
`$user_form = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($entity, 'register');`

Answer (score 5):

Entity forms don't work without an entity. If you want an empty form then use a newly created entity instance. You can use this example from the node entity:

```php
/**
 * Provides the node submission form.
 *
 * @param \Drupal\node\NodeTypeInterface $node_type
 *   The node type entity for the node.
 *
 * @return array
 *   A node submission form.
 */
public function add(NodeTypeInterface $node_type) {
  $node = $this->entityManager()->getStorage('node')->create(array(
    'type' => $node_type->id(),
  ));

  $form = $this->entityFormBuilder()->getForm($node);

  return $form;
}
```

The entity form builder is injected in the controller base class. So usually you use a controller to build entity forms.

When creating a node you need to define a bundle (content type), for which the entity form will be built. If your entity has no bundles you can use an empty array.

---

**Comments**

Comments need more work, because they are attached to an entity field.

Example how to build a form for the comment field of a node:

```php
$comment = $this->entityTypeManager()->getStorage('comment')->create([
  'entity_type' => 'node',
  'entity_id' => $node->id(),
  'field_name' => 'comment',
]);
$build = $this->entityFormBuilder()->getForm($comment);
```

Or the same outside of a controller without injected services:

```php
$comment = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('comment')->create([
  'entity_type' => 'node',
  'entity_id' => $node->id(),
  'field_name' => 'comment',
]);
$build = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($comment);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, if we altered a form and added #after_build. 
#after_build method is not working. Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify, the below code does work for me in Drupal 8.2.x:

```
$form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm(Drupal\user\Form\UserLoginForm::class);
```

Comment: When I tried your code it initially didn't work, but adding a \ in front of 'Drupal\user\Form\UserLoginForm::class' made it work. When I tried doing it with my custom class, I got the same error though. I've tried updated my question with my entity definition - my guess is that I haven't implemented something that I'd need to implement for your code to work.

Comment: Okay, I finally noticed that the example form you used *isn't* an entity form, it just extends from FormBase. I need to render an entity form (Specifically a content entity, something that extends from ContentEntityForm)

Comment: Yes, for my use case this is wrong.