# Rendering a form using \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($entity, 'default') is returning a plain form, before hook_form_alter

Tags: 8, forms

I'm rendering a form programmatically. The following code works:

```
$addressForm = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('profile')
  ->create(array('type' => 'customer', 'uid' => $uid));
$finalform =  $this->entityFormBuilder()->getForm($addressForm);
```

However, it is rendering the form before `hook_form_alter()` has been called.

For example, in `hook_form_alter()` we added a `#after_build` callback method and custom validations, but the changes made in these functions are not reflected in `$finalform`.

How do I ensure `hook_form_alter()` changes are made to the rendered output?

**.module file**

```
function custom_profile_form_profile_customer_add_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['formtitle'] =  array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#weight' => -100,
    '#markup' => '<h2>Old Address Form</h2>',
  );
  /* ....
.... */
}

function custom_profile_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'form_FORM_ID_alter') {
    $group = $implementations['custom_profile'];
    unset($implementations['custom_profile']);
    $implementations['custom_profile'] = $group;
  }
}
```

**.routing.yml**

I have created a new route for the Address page in /modules/custom/custom_profile/custom_profile.routing.yml,

```
commerce_add_address.get:
  path: '/checkout/{uid}/customer/add'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\custom_profile\Controller\newAddressBook::commerce_add_address'
  options:
    parameters:
      uid:
        type: integer
  methods:  [GET,POST]
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

**Controller**

in src/Controller/newAddressBook.php file

```
public function commerce_add_address($uid) {
  //To get profile Add Address form
  $addressForm = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getStorage('profile')
      ->create(array( 
        'type' => 'customer',
        'uid'  => $uid
      ));

  $finalform = $this->entityFormBuilder()->getForm($addressForm);
  $build['#theme'] = 'usernewaddress';
  $build['#data'] = array();
  $build['#data']['form'] = $finalform;

  return $build;
```

Comment: just now implemented hook_module_implements_alter(), No luck. form_alter callback function are not triggered.

Comment: Please add your `hook_module_implements_alter()` code to your question.

Comment: @leymannx any other idea? to render/trigger form_alter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that your implementation of `hook_form_alter()` runs at the right time via [`hook_module_implements_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/8.3.x).

> This hook is invoked during
>   `\Drupal::moduleHandler()->getImplementations()`. A module may implement
>   this hook in order to reorder the implementing modules, which are
>   otherwise ordered by the module's system weight.

But pay attention when using possible variations of `hook_form_alter()`.

> Note that hooks invoked using `\Drupal::moduleHandler->alter()` can have
>   multiple variations(such as `hook_form_alter()` and
>   `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`). `\Drupal::moduleHandler->alter()` will call
>   all such variants defined by a single module in turn. For the purposes
>   of `hook_module_implements_alter()`, these variants are treated as a
>   single hook. Thus, to ensure that your implementation of
>   `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` is called at the right time, you will have
>   to change the order of `hook_form_alter()` implementation in
>   `hook_module_implements_alter()`.

See? Right now you are checking for `if ($hook == 'form_FORM_ID_alter')` which won't work. Fix it by replacing it with `if ($hook == 'form_alter')`.

---

If that doesn't work try to change your module's weight via [`module_set_weight()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21module.inc/function/module_set_weight/8.3.x).