# How do I render the page to add products into my custom module?

Tags: commerce

Here is my code

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\mymodule\Controller;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
class HelloController extends ControllerBase
{
  public function content() {

       $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('\Drupal\commerce_product\Form\ProductForm');
}
}
```

I want to render the default add to product page(product/add/default) in my custom module controller file .

> Error: Call to a member function getEntityTypeId() on null in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityForm->getBaseFormId()  (line 79 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityForm.php).

Comment: possible duplicate of https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/216480/how-do-i-programmatically-generate-an-entity-form/216484

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an empty product and use `entity.form_builder` service to generate the form.
Try the following.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Controller;

use Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\Product;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class HelloController extends ControllerBase {
  public function content() {
   $product = Product::create([
     'type' => 'default',
   ]);
  return  \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($product);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @berramou

Comment: This code work for me
public function content(Request $request) {
  $type = node_type_load("products"); 
  $p = \Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\Product::create([
     'type' => 'default',
   ]);
  return  \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($p);

Comment: You have set type to default so what is the use of `$type = node_type_load("products");`